# A data structure for many-to-many symmetric relationship (person friends problem)

Tags: java, collections, many-to-many

I'm kinda of a newbie. I have a question regarding which Java collection (no Hibernate, databases, etc.) is best to use to implement many-to-many symmetric relationship. HashMap with values V=sets of keys? But then delete, add operations become very slow... Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do it is use two Maps.  One `Map<Object1, Object2>`, and one `Map<Object2, Object1>`.

You could add each pair of related objects to both maps.  That way you can look up the relationships both ways really quickly.  You will also need to remove pairs from both maps when a relationship is removed.

Removal of the relationships becomes a little slow, but adding and finding is constant time.

Comment: If it's a many-to-many relation, then how would you efficiently retrieve a set of Object2 instances related to some Object1 instance?